# Clockwise sorting

Tags: c#, sorting, unity-game-engine

I need to sort a array of points in clockwise order.

I have this comparator:

```
 public static int isClockWise(Vector2 first, Vector2 second)
{
    if (first == second) return 0;

    float angle1 = Mathf.Atan2(first.x, first.y);
    float angle2 = Mathf.Atan2(second.x, second.y);

    if (angle1 < angle2)
        return 1;

    if (angle1 > angle2)
        return -1;

    // Check to see which point is closest
    return (first.sqrMagnitude < second.sqrMagnitude) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

This works fine for most of my purposes. But i have a special case. I have 2 special points. I need 1 to be at the start of the list and the other at the end of the list. How can i sort a list of points clockwise in such a manner that my 2 special point would end up on the beginning and the end of the list?

Comment: Your first point must have the property that it compares equal to itself and smaller than everything else; your second point must have the property that it compares equal to itself and greater than everything else. So write that code!

Comment: I note also that your method has a number of style problems. Methods should be named with PascalCase, not camelCase. Methods that return an integer are not "is" methods; "is" methods should return bool. Why does your style of if statements change from one line to two line to conditional operator? Be consistent.

Comment: If `isClockWise` is intended to have similar rules to `CompareTo`, I would be tempted to replace `if (angle1 < angle2) return 1; if (angle1 > angle2) return -1;` with `if(angle1 != angle2) return angle2.CompareTo(angle1);`